gpg-agent is not logging to file specified in `gpg-agent.conf`
Below is my gpg-agent.conf file, the log-file option specifies where to put log however even though gpg-agent works fine the log has never been created.
I'm thinking either the option is ignored or I'm missing some additional options?
My environment is Debian 12 therefore systemd, is it possible logs are put into some other log file? I want the log file to be written as set in gpg-agent.conf
# Set the time a cache entry is valid to n seconds.
default-cache-ttl 14400 # 4h

# Set the maximum time a cache entry is valid to n seconds.
max-cache-ttl 28800 # 8h

# Use program filename as the PIN entry.
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-qt

# This option asks the Pinentry to timeout after n seconds with no user input.
pinentry-timeout 120 # 2min

# Append all logging output to file
log-file /var/log/gpg-agent.log

gpg-agent docs and the gpg-agent.conf file is put into ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
I have checked both /var/log/user.log and /var/log/syslog and the agent is not logging there, only messages seen are that the agent was started by systemd
Below is troubleshooting output:
gpgconf --check-options gpg-agent


gpg-agent:Private Keys:/usr/bin/gpg-agent:1:1:

gpgconf --list-options gpg-agent

Monitor:1:0:Options controlling the diagnostic output:0:0::::
verbose:12:0:verbose:0:0::::
debug-level:24:1::1:1::"none::
log-file:8:1:write server mode logs to FILE:32:1:FILE:::"/var/log/gpg-agent.log
Configuration:1:0:Options controlling the configuration:0:0::::
disable-scdaemon:8:1:do not use the SCdaemon:0:0::::
enable-ssh-support:0:0:enable ssh support:0:0::::
ssh-fingerprint-digest:24:2:use ALGO to show ssh fingerprints:1:1:ALGO:"md5::
enable-putty-support:0:0::0:0::::
enable-extended-key-format:8:3::0:0::::
faked-system-time:0:3::1:1::::
Security:1:0:Options controlling the security:0:0::::
default-cache-ttl:24:0:expire cached PINs after N seconds:3:3:N:600::14400
default-cache-ttl-ssh:24:1:expire SSH keys after N seconds:3:3:N:1800::
max-cache-ttl:24:2:set maximum PIN cache lifetime to N seconds:3:3:N:7200::28800
max-cache-ttl-ssh:24:2:set maximum SSH key lifetime to N seconds:3:3:N:7200::
ignore-cache-for-signing:8:0:do not use the PIN cache when signing:0:0::::
no-allow-external-cache:8:0:disallow the use of an external password cache:0:0::::
no-allow-mark-trusted:8:1:disallow clients to mark keys as "trusted":0:0::::
Passphrase policy:1:1:Options enforcing a passphrase policy:0:0::::
enforce-passphrase-constraints:8:2:do not allow bypassing the passphrase policy:0:0::::
min-passphrase-len:24:1:set minimal required length for new passphrases to N:3:3:N:8::
min-passphrase-nonalpha:24:2:require at least N non-alpha characters for a new passphrase:3:3:N:1::
check-passphrase-pattern:8:2:check new passphrases against pattern in FILE:32:1:FILE:::
check-sym-passphrase-pattern:8:2::32:1::::
max-passphrase-days:24:2:expire the passphrase after N days:3:3:N:0::
enable-passphrase-history:8:2:do not allow the reuse of old passphrases:0:0::::
Pinentry:1:1:Options controlling the PIN-Entry:0:0::::
no-allow-loopback-pinentry:8:2:disallow caller to override the pinentry:0:0::::
grab:8:2:let PIN-Entry grab keyboard and mouse:0:0::::
pinentry-timeout:8:1:set the Pinentry timeout to N seconds:3:3:N:::120
allow-emacs-pinentry:8:1:allow passphrase to be prompted through Emacs:0:0::::


gpg-agent normally runs as a user service, therefore it is unlikely to have permissions to write into /var/log/. Even if you have given sufficient file/directory permissions, there might be AppArmor rules blocking it.
Set a log file path that points to a file in the home directory of the user that runs the gpg-agent.

I just tested this but log file was not created, gpgconf --list-options gpg-agent output:
log-file:8:1:write server mode logs to FILE:32:1:FILE:::"~/dev/gpg-agent.log and also did systemctl --user restart gpg-agent and also gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye

I have also added the following line to the gpg-agent.conf file debug-level basic reloaded (no reload error) but no change.

The gpg-agent man page says the log-file option appends log output to the specified file. It does not promise to create the file if it does not exist; perhaps you should pre-create the file for it with e.g. touch ~/dev/gpg-agent.log and then restart the agent?

Sadly didn't work, but according to output in my question it appears logging applies to "server mode logs", I've run gpg-agent --server --options ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf but even that did not write any log entries into existing file.
